# "Tools" button does not appear in toolbar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, 10k-tools, toolbar

On beta sites, it takes a mere 2K to receive 10K privileges. I've just acquired them on History SE and have had them for a full 12 hours *(pats self on back)*. However, the <kbd>Tools</kbd> button does not appear on the toolbar.

[image]

I have access (the `http://history.stackexchange.com/tools/` url works for me), but the button is still non-existent.

I'm using Chrome 22.0.1229.94 on Windows 7.

Comment: Erm, tools is not shown on Meta and Stack Overflow either; only the flag count is shown if high enough. You can get to Tools via the review link.

Comment: Hmm. That works for me. I've always seen screenshots showing a "tools" button with a little number beside it.

Comment: Try clicking on review, select the tools part, and go back to the main page.

Comment: Nope. Still shows the same.

Comment: I'm betting this was changed to avoid the weird situation where the header changes (er, one of the many weird situations where the header changes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Tools page is available under the "Review" section.  Previously, it would sometimes show in the topbar depending on whether you had last visited review or tools.  With the redesigned review page we decided to remove this oddity and make the top link always "review".